# H2: Load database from multiple sources

Tags: h2

Is there any way to pre-populate an H2 Database using multiple sources? I've only found examples of RUNSCRIPT with a single source. I am looking for something along the lines of the code below, but in this case, H2 seems to be looking for a file called "*.sql".

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:mydatabase;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:create/*.sql'\;RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:insert/*.sql'"/>
```